# How to mix PHP URLs for a page?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have a website that use this URL type:

```
www.example.com/?page=first.php&id=100
```

as you can see I have page systems; I check the `$_GET` array for page variable if I found it I bring the page from the pages folder. And for the variables used inside page I use `&` to add it to the URL.

Now I add news system to my website this system has a main page which shows news titles so I could add it as a page `news.php` like this:

```
www.example.com/?page=news.php
```

my problem is when I should click on some title to see the news page. News are located in a folder called news and categorized in dates folder for example :

```
www.example.com/news/2014/05/news1.php
```

when I click this link, it gives me the news page but without my website left side, right side, header, footer.
I can not change my website URL system because search engine give this links a good rank and I can not change the news URL system also because this is the best way to show the news by date
I want to know if there is a way to make the two URL working together??

index.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
//Config Section NEEDED FILES
$server_root="./";
require_once("{$server_root}config.php");
require_once("{$server_root}include-sql/mysql.class.php");
require_once("{$server_root}include-php/LimitPagination.php");//pagenation class
//$db Connect to DB Uses All Over the Site
Global $db;
$db = new db_mysql($conf['db_hostname'], $conf['db_username'], $conf['db_password'], $conf['db_name']);
//facebook requirments
require("{$server_root}facebook_src/src/facebook.php");
include_once("{$server_root}my_functions.php");
//Site Structure

if(empty($_GET['page']))
{
    include_once("{$server_root}include-structure/header.php");
    if(file_exists("{$server_root}include-structure/content.php"))
    {
        include_once("{$server_root}include-structure/content.php");
        include_once("{$server_root}include-structure/footer.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo"The Content is Missing";
    }
}
else
{
        elseif(file_exists("{$server_root}pages/$page"))
    {
        include_once("{$server_root}include-structure/header.php");
        include_once("{$server_root}pages/$page");
        include_once("{$server_root}include-structure/footer.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo '404 Error This page does not Exist';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's only your content that's changing, you want to do something like:

```
include("{$server_root}include-structure/header.php");
if ($_GET['page'] != "") {
    include("{$server_root}include-structure/" . $page . ".php");
} else {
    include("{$server_root}include-structure/home.php");
}
include("{$server_root}include-structure/footer.php");
```

And change your links to look like

?page=home

So that you're always loading the header and footer, regardless of if the page exists. What you're doing is pointing directly to the include file. So it's loading it, but it's not going through all the other include steps etc.